# Doctrine2: first OneToMany relationship works, second doesn't?

Tags: doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a class that contains two OneToMany relationships.
Here is the sql squema
[image]

and here are the different classes.
**Movies**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="movies")
 * @property bigint $id
 * @property date $date
 * @property int $revision
 * @property string $original_title
 * @property string $thumbnail
 * @property string $plot
 */
class Movie {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="bigint");
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="date")
    */
    protected $date;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
    */
    protected $revision;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $original_title;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $thumbnail;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $plot;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Exhibition", mappedBy="movie", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    protected $exhibitions;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="movie", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    protected $categories;
}
```

**Exhibition**

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="exhibitions")
* @property bigint $id
* @property string $title
* @property string $type
*/
class Exhibition
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="bigint");
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $title;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Schedule", mappedBy="exhibition", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    protected $schedules;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie", inversedBy="exhibitions") 
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $movie;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cinema", inversedBy="exhibitions") 
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cinema", referencedColumnName="name", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $where;
}
```

**Category**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @property string $name
 */
class Category {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="id")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $name;

    /** 
     *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie", inversedBy="categories")
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $movie;
}
```

As you can see, both exhibitions and categories are OneToMany/ManyToOne relationships within the class Movie. The exhibitions parts works fine, but the the caregories parts doesn't.

Whenever I try to use, for instance: $movies[0]->categories, I get an internal server error. But for exhibitions everything works fine.

What am I missing here?
Is this the way to go for my setup?

Thank you!

Comment: Which internal server error?

Answer (score 0):

Could be because your categories primary key does not match up to your data model.  The variable here should be $id not $name.

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="id")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $name;
```